# setting the color of a cube with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I built a box in a function where its value is assigned to a variable called `box` then I tried to set the color of the node by pressing "w" invoking my box variable and defining it as another arbitrary variable.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first three.js app</title>
<style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 
    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    camera.position.z = 5;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    var box= function() {

        this.root = new THREE.Object3D;
}
    box.prototype.buildBox = function(){

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.3, 0.1 );


        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        color: "white",  // CSS color names can be used!
        } );

        var a= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        this.root.add(a);
        return this.root;

};
this.scene.add(this.buildBox());
document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);
function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
    var keyCode = event.which;
    this.Box = new box();
    var b = this.Box.buildBox();
    var keyCode = event.which;
    if (keyCode == 87)  {
        b.material.color.setHex (0xfff00);

}

    render();
</script>
```

Comment: do you get any errors? What is the output currently? Try using `console.log()` if you haven't already :)

Comment: From what I see, there are quite a lot of things that are going wrong. Could you try to find out if each part works as you expect, and fix things which don't, so that you can narrow down your question to a specific part of the code that you still don't understand?

Comment: well I assume everything works correctly except my "onDocumentKeyDown(event)" function, I think Im invoking my buildBox function in a wrong way.